# Assign Value of Custom Wordpress Post/Page Meta Field to JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, wordpress, variables, meta

Is there a way via some lines of JavaScript to assign the value of a custom meta field in a Wordpress post/page to a JavaScript variable?

In other words, I've got a custom meta field in all my Wordpress posts and pages named "customamznsearch". I'd like to assign the value of that field to a JavaScript variable with the same name... or different name if need be.

Also, an added bonus would be to also define a static value for the variable if no data is available from that meta field.

This is the code that will be utilizing the "customamznsearch" variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "livcouintheci-20";
amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
amzn_assoc_region = "US";
amzn_assoc_textlinks = "";
amzn_assoc_linkid = "0c1ce8995df23ae16ec99d3bb32502ec";
amzn_assoc_default_category = "SportingGoods";
amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = customamznsearch;
</script>
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
```

This code will be displayed in an Enhanced Text Widget in the footer of my page. The Enhanced Text widget should be fully capable of supporting Text, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Flash, Shortcodes, and PHP.

Comment: One way might be to add a hidden input to your page which takes the value of your custom meta data. You can then quite easily use DOM queries with javascript to pull out the value you need. A simple if statement could be used to determine if the value of that input is empty and you could assign some arbitrary value in the condition statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, the following snippet of code was what ended up working (please note that I decided to change the variable to 'amazonadserach'):

```
var amazonadsearch = "<?php global $post;
$amazonadsearch = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'amazonadsearch', true);
echo $amazonadsearch; ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just output javascript code from php like this:

```
<script>
var customamznsearch = "<?php echo addcslashes($customamznsearch, '"'); ?>";
</script>
```

Or if you mean to get it from the `<meta>` tags, then:

```
function getMeta(metaName) { 
   var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 

   for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
      if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") == metaName) { 
         return metas[i].getAttribute("content"); 
      } 
   } 

    return "";
}

var twitterTitle = getMeta("twitter:title");
```

Comment: Thanks Gavriel... I added some more details to the description above. When I tried adding the JavaScript snippet you suggested to the code above, it doesn't seem to be working. Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: I think you should try the 1st solution (from php) just make sure you print that line with the var cudtomamznsearch = "..." before the other JavaScript that uses it. BTW, did you get any JavaScript error when you tried the 2nd solution?